# Merging the SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our team is assigned a project on database. We are all set to start. But we will be working at our homes.

Each member is given tables to create, insert MBs of data, and write one table-orientes triggers and stored pros.

But ultimately we will have to merge then in a single database file and each member will be having his .mdf file of his tables.

How to we merge these tables???

We need to combine all the data into a single database file only....

Please bear with me if this question is a cake! I'm just a newbie :-)

Comment: ".mdf" -- I would assume we are talking about a version of Access then?

Comment: Naa... We have a .mdf file for SQL Server 2008 R2....

Comment: Do you each of you (M users) have N separate tables, with separate names, so the resulting database will have NxM tables? Or N tables with same names, so the resulting database will have N tables with merged data?

Comment: ".mdf" is for SQL Server. ".mdb" is for MS Access.

Comment: @ypercube : N*M tables will be there.
I would also want to know the procedure for N tables please....

Comment: @killerCoder: that is harder and requires more checks between changes. What happens if a member adds a field `newfield INT` and another member adds `newfield CHAR(10)` in same table? The first script run in the common database will execute, the second will raise error. I haven't tried such collaboration project but someone else with more experience can answer. You should add that optional requirement in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving objects from one database to another is easily achieved by scripting the objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx

Once the individual work is done, script out the tables, stored procedures, triggers, views, etc, and create them in your target database (this can be on a different server).

Then you can use the Import and Export Wizard to move your data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware you can't merge the .mdf files in the way you are thinking.

The closest approach I can think of is as follows...

Each person:
1. works on their own database with UNIQUE database names
2. also has a 'clone' of what will be the final databases
3. creates a script that copies their database structure and data to the 'clone'

You can then attach each .mdf file to the master SQL Server (as seperate and distinct databases).  You then run each person's script, copying from the attached .mdf's into the master copy of the final database.

In general I would strongly advise use of script based alterations to a database, allowing version control, etc, through versioning of the scripts.